# Is there a intersection function for vectors?

Tags: vector, set, common-lisp

Very often one finds statements that lists have a performance disadvantage compared to vectors because of consing and additional gc steps and some function work on generic sequences accepting lists and vectors.

But some functions like `intersection` expect two lists. Is there a library providing an alternative for vectors?

I started with something like this, but have the feeling that there should be a more mature solution.

```
(defun vec-intersec (vec-1 vec-2 &aux (result (make-array 0 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0)))
  "A simple implementation of intersection for vectors instead of lists."
  (loop :for v1 :across vec-1
        :if (find v1 vec-2 :test #'equal)
          :do (vector-push-extend v1 result))
  result)
```

Comment: Your operations are quadratic.
If you are performance-conscious, use hash tables.
Otherwise convert to lists.

Comment: Could you explain "use hash tables" more? Instead of vectors or as an intermediate structure to avoid `find`?

Comment: HT membership testing has constant costs, so using them to represent sets makes sense. `Find` is linear, so it is always suboptimal. Either trees/sorted lists (logarithmic access) or HT is the way to go, depending on your usage patterns (do you modify your sets often?)

Comment: I see, I will test which approach is the most suitable for my current example. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It always depends on the size of your collection and what you want to do with it.

Below about 20 to 50 elements, lists are often perfectly OK even for random access (if you're not in a tight inner loop, or consing a lot).

If you already have vectors, it might be most convenient to sort one of them so that you can do a binary search instead of a naïve linear one.  If that is not enough, and your collections bigger, putting the elements into a hash-table (as keys, with an appropriate `:test`) gives you faster (amortized) lookup.

This should take you quite far.  If you identify an issue that cannot be solved in such a simple way, you might want to look into [FSet](https://github.com/slburson/fset) or [CL-Containers](https://github.com/gwkkwg/cl-containers), which support more advanced data structures.

Comment: Alternatively, slurp the elements of one of them (the shorter, probably, if there's a difference) into a hash table, then use the hash table for quick presence checks.

Comment: @Vatine: yes, that's the gist of the second part of the third paragraph.